# close fancybox from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a function that gets executed when clicking on certain things within the content of my fancybox.  The functions work fine, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to close fancybox programmatically. I have tried:

`$.fancybox.close()` and `parent.$.fancybox.close();`
I have even tried triggering a `click` to the close button but that has not worked either.

When I try `$.fancybox.close()` I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined
```

Here is what my fancybox call looks like:

```
<a href="#display" class="fancybox" id="query" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000;" title="" data-fancybox-width="950">Open</a>
```

Here is what my function looks like (attached to the parent page's head)

```
$(document).on('click', ".group_box", function(e){

var nodeName = e.target.nodeName
//validation to ensure an input button was not pressed
if (nodeName != "INPUT"){
    $.fancybox.close();
  }
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: you are opening inline content, aren't you? what version of fancybox?

Comment: @JFK When the fancybox <a> is clicked, ajax gets fed into the div which fancybox displays.  Newest version of fancybox.

Comment: @JFK version: 2.1.5 (Fri, 14 Jun 2013)

Comment: so I guess the selector `.group_box` also gets fed into the "#display" div via ajax, doesn't it?

Comment: @JFK yes.  If I can figure out how to refer to the open instance of fancybox, I SHOULD be able to invoke close.  I am unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options :

1). Create a close button (with an `<a>` tag) and pass the `$.fancybox.close()` method directly into its `href` attribute like "

```
<a class="closeFancybox1" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close()">close option 1</a>
```

This link can be added by your ajax call inside the `#display` `div` or you can append it to the fancybox content after show.

2). Create a close button using a **unique selector** and bind a `click` event to it to trigger the `$.fancybox.close()` method only until is visible inside fancybox

so having this html inside your fancybox content

```
<a class="closeFancybox2" href="javascript:;">close option 2</a>
```

bind a `click` event to it to trigger the `$.fancybox.close()` method using the `afterShow` callback like

```
afterShow: function () {
    $(".fancybox-inner").on("click", ".closeFancybox2", function () {
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
}
```

**Notice** we still used `.on()` in its delegated form.

see <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Meg/)</kbd> using both options.

Comment: i have not tried these yet but they appear to work according to the fiddle.  In this case, you have created two links within fancybox to close. I need fancybox to close under certain requirements of things clicked.  Could I trigger a 'click' event to this <a> through jquery?  For example, in my original .group_box click, could I have $('.closefancybox2 a').trigger('click'); ??

Comment: `.closefancybox2 a` is the wrong selector, it should rather be `a.closefancybox2` as in my example

Comment: I tried the first method with no luck.  'close' is not a method of undefined.  Is there a way I can call the click event of the close button already provided by fancybox?  I have given it an id, and then used $('#fancyboxclose').find('a').trigger('click');  (as well as what you have demonstrated) with no luck. Am I doing something in the click event wrong?

Comment: does it make a difference that I'm doing this cross domain? IE, I open fancybox locally, it gets fed ajax from cross domain..