# After opening Fancybox with ajax, $.fancybox.close() not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

If I open fancybox with ajax, I cannot find a way to close the window with custom button within the iframe.

```
$.fancybox.open({
                    // fancybox API options
                    href: "/pricing/actuator/select",
                    type: 'ajax',
                    ajax: {
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {width: widthValue, height: heightValue, mult_height: multHeightValue, mult_width: multWidthValue, qty: qtyValue, lineItemIndex: index}
                    },
                    fitToView: false,
                    width: 1074,
                    height: '100%',
                    autoSize: false,
                    closeClick: false,
                    openEffect: 'none',
                    closeEffect: 'none',
                    closeBtn: true,
                    helpers     : {
                        overlay : {closeClick: false} 
                    }
                });
```

I have tried all kinds of methods:

```
parent.$('body').fancybox.close();
parent.$.fancybox.close();
$.fancybox.close();
$.parent.fancybox.close();
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
window.top.window.$.fancybox.close();
```

Nothing works. I end up using:

```
parent.$('.fancybox-overlay').css('display', 'none');
parent.$('.fancybox-wrap').css('display', 'none');
```

But there has to be a better solution.

Comment: My guess? your ajax content is triggering a JS error therefore it prevents fancybox methods from working (check for errors in your console after loading your ajax content) ... I also hope you understand the difference between opening ajax content and iframe content

Comment: Ajax content works pretty much to inline content so check this if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/21009138/1055987

Comment: There are no console errors. I know the difference. I would rather post variables than add them as my URL parameters. Is there a way to use Iframe and post variables?